# htaccess, how can I use gzip compression + hide .html extensions?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, gzip, hide

I'm using 1and1 and I'm following this guide in order to compress as much of my website as I can:

http://mrrena.blogspot.com/2009/01/how-to-compress-php-and-other-text.html?showComment=1328550165472#c3296286447260746640

I was previously also using my htaccess file to hide the .html extensions of each webpage. Now that I've applied the new code to compress everything by routing it through php, I am no longer hiding html extensions, and many of my weblinks are subsequently broken. Here's a copy paste of my htaccess file.

```
Header unset Pragma
FileETag None
Header unset ETag

# cache images/pdf docs for 10 days
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=864000, public, must-revalidate"
  Header unset Last-Modified
</FilesMatch>

# cache html/htm/xml/txt diles for 2 days
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|xml|txt|xsl)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

# tells the server to process all the file extensions specified through PHP5 for compression purposes
RemoveHandler .css
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php .shtml .html .htm .txt .js .css .ttf .svg .woff

#
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
#
# REDIRECT /folder/index.html to /folder/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.html$ http://weaverinnovations.com/$1 [R=301,L]
#
```

This sort of thing is well beyond my area of expertise, and any help as well as an explanation of how to get around the conflict would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe an obvious question, but did you restart your browser between making the .htaccess changes regarding the the .html extension? Having used 301 redirects your browser will "remember" these until you restart.... more than one headache has been caused by overlooking this fact.

Answer (score 0):

## Performance

> This sort of thing is well beyond my area of expertise, ...

Well in this case, I would "keep it simple stupid".  I've probably more knowledge of the bowels of this.  Using PHP as a wrapper for static files add ~100 mSec on each file access and *not* a good idea.

If you want some suggestions on how to tune you app for responsiveness have a look at my blog tags, [Webfusion](http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/search-Webfusion) and [Performance](http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/search-Performance), which give some very specific tuning advice for *this* hosting provider.  My blog runs on the same hosting infrastructure (Webfusion is just another brand name in the same company)  You will see that I have a Google Pagespeed score of 99/100 which is as good as the Google home page achieves, so I doubt that you'll improve on this.  (Yours is currently 56/100).  My current rules are:

```
AddType image/x-icon .ico
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/css        "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon    "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg      "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/gif       "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType image/png       "access plus 1 week"

<Files "sitemap.*">
   ForceType text/xml
</Files>

<Files "rss*">
   ForceType text/xml
</Files>

AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain test/css text/xml application/xml

<FilesMatch "\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png|pdf)$">
   Header add "Cache-Control" "public, max-age=604800"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|html)$">
   Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
```

Using a "must revalidate" directive is ill-advised if you have a PHP wrapper for static files, especially on a shared hosting service, because you still pay the PHP image startup penalties and you need to process the **If-Modified-Since** and **If-None-Match** request headers and issue the 304 response correctly.

## HTML links broken

It really helps if you ask one question per question and not two.  Can you describe in more detail exactly what weblinks are "broken" by giving some specific before and after examples, then perhaps we can give a specific response.